# Delphi Generic constraints problem

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2009

I am trying to create a generic list class for use with tiOPF (an Object Persistence Framework for delphi @ www.tiopf.com).  Specifically I am trying to take an existing generic class (TtiObjectList) and make a generic version that uses TtiObject descenants.

I have limited scope for altering the base classes as they need to compile under D7 - D2009 and Free Pascal.  I need to descend from TtiObjectList to keep the existing persistence mechanisms working.

```
// base class  
type  
  TtiObjectList = class(TtiObject)
...  
protected  
  function GetItems(i: integer): TtiObject; virtual;  
  procedure SetItems(i: integer; const AValue: TtiObject); virtual;  
...  
public  
  function Add(const AObject : TtiObject): integer; overload; virtual;  
...  
end;
```

My class is defined as follows:

```
TtiGenericObjectList<T: TtiObject> = class(TtiObjectList)  
protected  
  function GetItems(i:integer): T; reintroduce;  
  procedure SetItems(i:integer; const Value: T); reintroduce;  
public  
  function Add(const AObject: T): integer; reintroduce;  
  property Items[i:integer]: T read GetItems write SetItems; default;  
end;

implementation

{ TtiGenericObjectList<T> }

function TtiGenericObjectList<T>.Add(const AObject: T): integer;  
var obj: TtiObject;  
begin  
  obj:= TtiObject(AObject); /// Invalid typecast
  result:= inherited Add(obj);  
end;  

// alternate add, also fails  
function TtiGenericObjectList<T>.Add(const AObject: T): integer;  
begin  
  result:= inherited Add(AObject); /// **There is no overloaded version**
 /// **of 'Add' that can be called with these arguments**  
end;  

function TtiGenericObjectList<T>.GetItems(i: integer): T;  
begin  
  result:= T(inherited GetItems(i)); /// **Invalid typecast  **
end;  

procedure TtiGenericObjectList<T>.SetItems(i: integer; const Value: T);  
begin  
  inherited SetItems(i, Value);  
end;
```

The problem I have is that delphi is not seeing T as a TtiObject descendant.  I am getting invalid typecast errors when I do something like:

```
function TtiGenericObjectList<T>.Add(const AObject: T): integer;  
var obj: TtiObject;  
begin  
  obj:= TtiObject(AObject); /// **Invalid typecast***
  result:= inherited Add(obj);  
end;
```

If I don't do a type cast, then I get overload errors instead as shown in the listing above.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Sean

Comment: This was a bug in the Delphi 2009 compiler; I think it was was solved in the Delphi 2010 compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is not me, but the compiler :).

In the end, I have hacked around it using the following methods

```
class function TtiGenericObjectList<T>.GenericAsObject(const Value): TObject;
begin
  Result := TObject(Value);
end;

class function TtiGenericObjectList<T>.ObjectAsGeneric(const Value): T;
begin
  Result := T(Value);
end;
```

used as follows

```
function TtiGenericObjectList<T>.Add(const AObject: T): integer;
var obj: TtiObject;
begin
  obj:= TtiObject(GenericAsObject(AObject));
  result:= inherited Add(obj);
  // replaces the following which gets overload errors
//   result:= inherited Add(TtiObject(AObject));
end;
```

and

```
function TtiGenericObjectList<T>.GetItems(i: integer): T;
var obj: TtiObject;
begin
  obj:= inherited GetItems(i);
  result:= ObjectAsGeneric(obj);
  // replaces the following which gets "Invalid typecast" errors
  // result:= inherited Add(AObject);
end;
```

I will clean these up a bit and use them till the compiler gets fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The Delphi 2009 compiler has a few very serious flaws in its generics implementation.  It doesn't understand the implications of constraints nearly as well as it ought to, (Barry Kelly admitted this somewhere else on SO; I don't remember exactly where,) and cross-unit generics can cause very strange problems.  Best bet is to handle this one on a case-by-case basis:  If your code compiles, use it.  If not, go back to a non-generic implementation until they get it fixed.  Hopefully we'll see an update that fixes generics (and the Generics.Collections unit) sometime in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

I recently tackled a similar problem using D2010, and here is the code I came up with.

```
type
  TGenericList<T: TtiObject> = class(TtiObjectList)
  protected
    function GetItems(AIndex: integer): T; reintroduce;
    procedure SetItems(AIndex: integer; const AValue: T); reintroduce;
  public
    property Items[i:integer]: T read GetItems write SetItems; default;
    function Add(const AObject: T): integer; reintroduce;
  end;

implementation

{ TGenericList<T> }

function TGenericList<T>.Add(const AObject: T): integer;
begin
  Result := inherited Add(TtiObject(AObject));
end;

function TGenericList<T>.GetItems(AIndex: integer): T;
begin
  Result := T(inherited GetItems(AIndex));
end;

procedure TGenericList<T>.SetItems(AIndex: integer; const AValue: T);
begin
  inherited SetItems(AIndex, AValue);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found some little issues with generics, which is not surprising for such a new feature. And you are trying to confuse the compiler real hard ;-).

Unfortunately I have no 2009 at hand here so I can't test, but I have some suggestions:

Have you looked for updates (and installed them)?

Have you tried using the as and is operators:

```
obj:= AObject as TtiObject;
```

Have you tried using an intermediate class:

```
TtiGenericList<T: TObject> = class(TtiObjectList)  
protected  
  function GetItems(i:integer): T; reintroduce;  
  procedure SetItems(i:integer; const Value: T); reintroduce;  
public  
  function Add(const AObject: T): integer; reintroduce;  
  property Items[i:integer]: T read GetItems write SetItems; default;  
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

(I got here due to a similar problem, but while nailing it down I got to a different solution, though with a newer(XE) Delphi):

Or simply try to make that local variable **Obj** of type T.